# Prove using Comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum b_n$ and $\sum a_n$ are series with positive terms and $\sum b_n$ is convergent. Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{a_n}{b_n}$=0, $a_n$ is also convergent.

Proof at level of Single variable Calc, please.

Comment: Intuitively the given limit tells you that the $a_n$'s are smaller than then $b_n$'s. This is enough for convergence of the series. **Edit:** You can even drop the hypothesis that $a_n>0$.

Comment: I don't think we can drop the hypothesis, as a_n could go to negative infinity?

Comment: Then you can't get the limit of the ratio to be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum b_n$ is convergent, it means $b_n \to 0$, i.e. $\frac{1}{b_n} \to 
\infty$. But we know that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 0$, hence $a_n$ is an infinitesimal of higher order, hence $a_n < b_n \ \forall n >N$, hence $\sum_n a_n$ converges. One example would be $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $a_n = e^{-n}$